# Repeat last environment by command

Tags: macros, environments, content-replication, songbook

I am creating a book with guitar chords using a customized version of the [songbook package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/songbook?lang=de). As most songs use the same chorus multiple times, I created the very simple macro `\refChorus` which just prints out **[Chorus]** and is defined like so:

```
\newcommand*{\refChorus}{\textsf{\textbf{[Chorus]}}}
```

Pretty basic.
In the songbook package, a chorus is contained in the **SBChorus** environment. Now here's my question:

Is it possible in `LaTeX` to change the `\refChorus` command so it repeats the last chorus? Implementation wise I would guess that I just define a variable which is updated with each chorus occurrence to hold the content of that environment and then a command to just print out this variable. Unfortunately I have no idea how to accomplish that.

I want to redefine the command `\refChorus` so this code

```
\begin{SBChorus}
    This is chorus 1
\end{SBChorus}
\refChorus
\refChorus

\begin{SBChorus}
    This is chorus 2
\end{SBChorus}
\refChorus
```

Outputs

**This is chorus 1**

**This is chorus 1**

**This is chorus 1**

**This is chorus 2**

**This is chorus 2**

EDIT:
I have been asked to provide a compilable example. This is it:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[chordbk]{songbook} 

\newcommand*{\refChorus}{\textsf{\textbf{[Chorus]}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{song}{Songtitle} %Songtitel
        {} %in my version of songbook I am not using this
        {} %or this
        {Composer} 
        {Album} 
        {Year} 

        \begin{SBChorus}
            Chorus with a \Ch{C}{chord}
        \end{SBChorus}

        \refChorus %this just outputs [Chorus] but it should just repeat the last chorus (ideally the first chorus of a song if there's multiple in one song)

    \end{song}

    \begin{song}{Title Song 2} %Songtitel
        {} %in my version of songbook I am not using this
        {} %or this
        {Composer} 
        {Album} 
        {Year} 

        \begin{SBChorus}
            Chorus 2 with a \Ch{G}{chord}
        \end{SBChorus}

        \refChorus %this just outputs [Chorus] but it should just repeat the last chorus (ideally the first chorus of a song if there's multiple in one song)

    \end{song}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please do not post such fragments only. Provide a compilable document. It should be possible if you catch the content of the environment `SBChorus`.

Comment: According to your definition, `\refChorus` has an argument, but you call it without argument, this will lead to errors

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following macros redefine the environment `SBChorus` such that it

- stores its contents in the macro `\lastChorus` which then is used by `\refChorus` if used without an optional argument
- stores its contents under a name given as an optional argument to the `SBchorus` environment, which then can be used by `\refChorus` if given this name as optional argument.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[wordbk]{songbook}
\usepackage{environ,ifthen}
\let\origSBChorus\SBChorus
\let\origendSBChorus\endSBChorus
\RenewEnviron{SBChorus}[1][]%
  {\global\let\lastChorus\BODY
   \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
     {}%
     {\expandafter\global\expandafter\let\csname BODY:SBchorus:#1\endcsname\BODY}%
   \origSBChorus\lastChorus\origendSBChorus
  }
\newcommand\refChorus[1][]%
   {\origSBChorus
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
      {\lastChorus}%
      {\csname BODY:SBchorus:#1\endcsname}
    \origendSBChorus
   }
\begin{document}
\begin{SBChorus}[main]% chorus gets label "main"
    This is chorus 1
\end{SBChorus}
\refChorus      % refers to the last chorus
\refChorus[main]% refers to the chorus labeled "main" (which happens to be last chorus)

\begin{SBChorus}
    This is chorus 2
\end{SBChorus}
\refChorus      % refers to the last chorus (which is the second one)
\refChorus[main]% refers to the chorus labeled "main" (which was the first one)
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works great, thanks!
As every SBChorus is nested in a song environment, would it be possible to only redefine the variable for the first chorus in a song or even store all choruses of a song in an array, accessible via `\refChorus[1]` etc.?

Comment: @Taxel I've updated my answer. Storing the choruses in an array is not the best solution, since the numbers may change when inserting a new chorus. With my updated solution you can now assign a name to a chorus and later recall it under this name.